# How to customize "--help" with Click?

Tags: python, python-click

Help messages in Click are [accessed via the long option `--help`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/quickstart/#basic-concepts-creating-a-command) by default. How can I also make the short option `-h` available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `context_settings` with `help_option_names`:

```
CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help'])

@click.command(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
def cli():
    pass
```

This is straight out of [the docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/documentation/#help-parameter-customization).